# How to execute system() without any output

Tags: php

I have a basic php script that calls system("netstat -l") and the reads what services are online. I got it all working exept that system() sends the whole return to the client... So my question is how do i run system() whiteout having it sending the command output to the client?

Im running this on ubuntu server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$output = shell_exec('netstat -l');
```

`$output` will now contain the output of the command.

[shell_exec](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use shell_exec(). It will return the output of the command, instead of printing it like system().